# On the construction of orthogonal polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation, orthogonality, orthogonal-polynomials

In the following proof, argument goes on based on considering $C_n$ to be nonzero then it finishes the proof for $C_n=0$ :
[image]
Also if we set $C_n=0$ in Eq. (6.10) then must $m=0,1,2,...,n- 2$ in Eq. (6.12). In either case the proof fails. Am I right? If so, how to finish the proof, that is showing $\Delta_n \ne 0$?

Comment: Why did you exclude $m=n-1$?

Comment: @metamorphy, when $C_n \ne 0$ (implicitly $C_{n+1} = 0$), $m=0,...,n-1$ so when $C_n = 0$ and $C_{n-1} \ne 0$ so the argument reduces by $1$ less i.e.: $m=0,...,(n-1)-1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You exclude $m=n-1$ for *no reason*. The proof proceeds by showing that $(6.10)$ has solutions $C_0,\ldots,C_n$ with $C_n\neq 0$. This amounts to proving $\Delta_n\neq 0$. If we assume the contrary, the *same* system with $C_n=0$ (consisting of $n$ equations, not $n-1$) has nontrivial solutions $C_0,\ldots,C_{n-1}$. This corresponds to $(6.12)$ with the allowed values of $m$ exactly *as specified there*.

Comment: We want to prove $\Delta_n\neq 0$ so we suppose the contrary $\Delta_n = 0$. This is OK. However, $C_n \ne 0$ was required from beginning and this assumption can't be changed otherwise it will be other argument *from the beginning* so (6.10) can't be used. For new argument I supposed $n-2$ the last $m$; for old one $C_n \ne 0$.

Comment: Maybe you get it this way: if $\Delta_n=0$ then the system $$\begin{align}M_0 C_0&+M_1 C_1+\ldots+M_{n-1}C_{n-1}&=&\color{red}{0}\\M_1 C_0&+M_2 C_1+\ldots+M_{n}C_{n-1}&=&\color{red}{0}\\ \ldots\\M_{n-1} C_0&+M_n C_1+\ldots+M_{2n-2}C_{n-1}&=&\color{red}{0}\end{align}$$ has solutions in $C_0,\ldots,C_{n-1}$ not all zero.

Comment: No I say that $C_n=0$ is not allowed even if $Δ_n=0$. When forming (6.10) we assumed $C_n \ne 0$.

Comment: Forget your $C_n$! Do you agree with the statement in my last comment *as written*? (If you don't, tell me why.)

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with all of your last comment. Let me re-read the proof again...

Comment: Cool ;) I think the author just didn't want to write down this almost-the-same system explicitly.

Comment: Thanks a lot :-)